# React library similar to Backbone Models/Collections

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any library which helps with manipulating downloaded JSON structure? I mean making some helpers like in BB Models eg. `isClosed()` which is equivalent `this.stage === 'open'` and so one.

If not do you have any idea how to implement this type of behavior in plain react, without using BB? 
I dont wanna use Redux in this case because I am fetching a lot of nested JSON structure data and sharing this only within one parent component.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Backbone Models/Collections in react, you can checkout my library that binds Backbone Models/Collections to React view. i.e. When your data changes, the React view trigger `forceUpdate`. Here is the link to [React.withBackbone](https://github.com/beanworks/React.withBackbone)